# JS function to hide blog posts

Tags: javascript

I created a blog website with 3 main categories: investing, money and retirement. I added a class element that corresponds to each topic category. I'm trying to create JS functions that, when clicked, hide the other two categories (I'm doing with to avoid having a homepage for each category). Here is one function to show the Retirement category by hiding the Investing and Money categories:

```
    function showRetirement() {
        var abc = document.getElementsByClassName("Investing, Money");
        for (var abc2 = 0; abc2 < abc.length; abc2++) {
        abc[abc2].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

Needless to say it doesn't work. Brackets is saying the function "is defined but never used." It is also saying the var abc " 'document' is not defined."

This is my link to the function:

```
<div class="nav-link" onclick="showRetirement()">Retirement</div>
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO Dan.

`getElementsByClassName` does not allow retrieving by multiple class names in one call.
Instead, it will be easier to use the `document.querySelectorAll()` method, which allows using query selectors to select items from the page.
A query selector to select all items with the class `Investing` OR `Money` would look like this:
`.Investing, .Money`

As a side note, the warnings in your brackets editor can be ignored at this point, the editor doesn't realise you are calling this function from an `onClick=""` handler and therefore thinks the function isn't use.

Another side note, it is conventional to use the variable `i` in for-loops, other programmers will more easily be able to understand what the variable is used for.

An example solution, using querySelectorAll

```
function showRetirement() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".Investing, .Money");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

It is also probably worth showing the items with the `Retirement` class here too, after we hide the others:

```
function showRetirement() {
    var elementsToHide = document.querySelectorAll(".Investing, .Money");
    for (var i = 0; i < elementsToHide.length; i++) {
        elementsToHide[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    var elementsToShow = document.querySelectorAll(".Retirement");
    for (var i = 0; i < elementsToShow.length; i++) {
        elementsToShow[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function showRetirement(){
 var ar_el;
 ar_el = document.getElementsByClassName("Investing");
 for (var i = 0; i < ar_el.length; i++)
  ar_el[i].style.display = "none";

 ar_el = document.getElementsByClassName("Money");
 for (var i = 0; i < ar_el.length; i++)
  ar_el[i].style.display = "none";

 ar_el = document.getElementsByClassName("Retirement");
 for (var i = 0; i < ar_el.length; i++)
  ar_el[i].style.display = "block";
```

}